# Usage of Variable in MySql LIMIT Clause in Version 5.7.18-log

Tags: mysql, limit

I am new to MySql but have been working MSSQL for quite some time. I need to implement Pagination in one of the Stored Procedures. I am aware of LIMIT Clause (similar to OFFSET in MSSQL), but I am unable to use a variable in the Clause and getting Query Syntax error. I am using MySql Version '5.7.18-log' and I am aware that variable in LIMIT is available from 5.5.6+. I tried many forums and blogposts; I have also tried the 5.7 documentation for help.
I am aware that there is a workaround for this by using dynamic prepared sql statements.
Is there any direct way of using LIMIT with Variable?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Here is the code, @Nigel Ren

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `USP_GetResults`(IN PageNumber INT,IN PageCount INT)
BEGIN
SET @pageOffset := (PageNumber - 1) * PageCount;
SELECT * FROM TableName
ORDER BY ColumnName LIMIT @pageOffset,PageCount;
END
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL statement, would make it a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, the type of variable I was using was wrong.
Solved it as shown in code snippet below.
Thanks for looking at the question, downvoting and not even answering. ;)
(I personally feel if you feel its very easy kindly help others by answering it)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `USP_GetResults`(IN PageNumber INT,IN PageCount INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE $PageOffset int;
SET $PageOffset = (PageNumber - 1) * PageCount;

SELECT * FROM TableName
ORDER BY ColumnName LIMIT $PageOffset,PageCount;
END
```